# Изменение определённого элемента в модели angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Добрый день.

У меня есть список студентов, где отображается Fio. Я хочу выделить определённого человека, где потом смогу изменить его имя. Как привязать <input> к конкретному человеку?

```
<li ng-repeat="Student in Students">
<a ng-href="#">{{Student.Fio}}</a>
</li>
```

И есть поле Фио `<input>`.

Я хочу привязать его к выбранному студенту, а точнее к контроллеру, чтоб можно было отслеживать изменение значения и отправлять новые данные на сервер.

Как такое сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
<input ng-model="Student.Fio" type="text"/>
```

Изменения в поле ввода будут отображаться в модели. Главное в контроллере определить саму модель.

Насчет отслеживания изменений:

```
<input ng-model="Student.Fio" ng-change="sendDataToServer()" type="text"/>
```

В js:

```
$scope.sendDataToServer = function () {
    $http.post('/path', {
        students: $scope.Students // передаете свою модель, на сервере парсите данные
    }).success(function (resp) {
        // logic
    });
};
```

В случае PHP, например, я беру данные на сервере так:

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); //просто $_POST приходит пустым
```